group by on slug in laravel eloquent
I have a table 'fields' in laravel . There i'm adding slug and client_id where client_id can be nullable. Now I have two entries in the table with same slug but in one row client_id is null and in another row client_id is available. How I can make group by if client_id is available then 2nd row and if client_id not available then first row using eloquent.



id
name
slug
client_id




1
name
first_name
null


2
name changed
first_name
1


.





.





.






Expected output:
Case 1 : If client_id not null then result needs to be 2nd row.
Case 2 : If client_id null then result needs to be 1st row.
I tried :
Field::select('slug', 'id', 'name','field_type')->groupBy('slug', 'id', 'name','field_type')->where(function($q) use($clientModel){
                return $q->whereNull('client_id')->orWhere('client_id', $clientModel->id);
            })->latest()->paginate(20)


You can do this by ordering your results such that non-null client_id values come first. I have pasted a modified query below:
    $field = Field::select('slug', 'id', 'name', 'field_type')
        ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(client_id)')
        ->orderBy('client_id', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('slug', 'id')
//        ->groupBy('slug', 'id')  //If you want to  group without  ID having just unique slugs  use this section instead 
        ->paginate(20);

This will first order your records in a way that rows with a non-null client_id are at the top, and then order them in descending order by client_id, which means if there are multiple non-null client_id entries for the same slug, the one with the highest client_id will be chosen. Finally, it groups by slug, which, combined with the ordering, should give you the desired result. note that I added a comment to show you can group in two ways.
one thing to consider is that I only tested with MySQL and If strict SQL mode is enabled or if you're using a different database system, you might not be able to do t
